# How to assert an element whether its visible or not without failing test by using if condition?

Tags: if-statement, cypress, assertion

My code looks like below, can someone help on this?

```
cy.visit(ws.visitEl())
cy.get('firstName').type('Jyothi')
cy.get('lastName').type('Prasad')           
cy.get('Work-email').type('123@gmail.com')
cy.get('JobTitle').select('CEO').should('be.visible')
cy.get('companyName').type('Google')
cy.get('signup-button').click()
```

Here, I need to write a code like if 'signup-button' is not enabled, I should find the error in the page like which field is throwing an error and so the test should not fail? So here if any field is not filled, it throws an error.

Please can anyone help on this?

Comment: If you are testing something, conditional testing can allow bugs to slip. Beware. If you are, you should separate test for each expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```js
cy.visit(ws.visitEl())
cy.get('firstName').type('Jyothi')
cy.get('lastName').type('Prasad')
cy.get('Work-email').type('123@gmail.com')
cy.get('JobTitle').select('CEO').should('be.visible')
cy.get('companyName').type('Google')
cy.get('signup-button').then(($btn) => {
  if ($btn.is(":disabled")) { //disabled
    cy.get('error selector').should('have.text', 'error text')
  } else { //enabled
    cy.wrap($btn).click()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked. I simply modified the code as per my requirement.

Comment: What if element is exist or not? How to perform. I tried using cy.get('body') and locator.should('exist') but no solution. cy.get('body').then($body=>{
        cy.log('then block')
            if($body.find('.event-master-jumpto').length > 0){
                cy.get('#btnIssueEventJumpTo').click({force: true})
                cy.log('button clicked')
            } else{
                cy.log('else block')
            }
        })
This printing only then block and else block.